# extend log4net SmtpAppender for dynamic To email address

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender, smtpappender

Ok. I have created custom SmtpAppender to use dynamic **To** email address.

Using  sample project given with Log4net - I have managed to use dynamic email address as below

```
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["ToProperty"] =  "swapneel@stackoverlfow.com";
```

and in my  ***custom  SMTPAppender***

```
        string mailMessageTo;
        if (ToProperty == null)
        {
            mailMessageTo = "DoNotReply@StaockOverlfow.com"            }
        else
        {
            var subjectWriter = new StringWriter(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            ToProperty.Format(subjectWriter, loggingEvent);
            mailMessageTo = subjectWriter.ToString();
        }
```

this code **is working** in sample application but when I am trying to use it in our "**Project**" **not working** for some reason.

I have 2 appenders in Log4net.config. EventLog is working as expected but CustomSmtpAppender is not sending any emails. **Any direction to resolve this issue.**

```
1] <appender name ="EmailLogAppender1" type ="MY.Company.ProjectName.Appenders.CustomSmtpAppender, 
    TRS">


2] <appender name ="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enabled [log4net internal debugging](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug)  and could see what was causing problem.

```
Add this to your Web.Config:

 <appSettings>
  <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true" />
 </appSettings>
 <system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true">
   <listeners>
    <add
     name="textWriterTraceListener"
     type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
     initializeData="c:\\log4net.txt" />
   </listeners>
  </trace>
 </system.diagnostics>
```