# extern alias 'xxx' was not specified in a /reference option

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

I am trying to use `log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["subjectProperty"]  = emailsubject`
in my project.

I have 2 differnt projects

1. Web - MVC
2. Business Layer

WEB - MVC project has reference to Combres

Business Layer has reference to log4net ([here i have extended SMTPAppender for dynamic email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157710/extend-log4net-smtpappender-for-dynamic-to-email-address/9158746#9158746) address)

So at runtime I am having this error:

> duplicate reference exists in Combres and log4Net for ThreadContext

I have added the **extern** keyword to resolve issue

I used the properties window to change the alias for the assembly from 'global' to 'MyAlias'

At the top of the file where the aliased assembly is used, I put `extern alias MyAlias`. This must be before any using statements.

I followed this:

> Use the alias prefix to use the namespace you want, for example using
>   `MyAlias::MyNamespace`.

But I have this error:

> The extern alias 'xxx' was not specified in a /reference option

Comment: This is not a duplicate. answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502640/the-extern-alias-xxx-was-not-specified-in-a-reference-option   in this questions are not helpful for me ..

Comment: So you've already edited the project file manually?

Comment: yes. Edited my Web project - still not working

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET project then?  That's important information which you NEED to add to the question.

Comment: Does it work from a "class library" project, which is in turn referenced by the web project?  Reference aliases might not be supported by ASP.NET.

Comment: If I use it without Combres then it works. Combres also has reference to log4net!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need a way to reference 2 different versions of the same 3rd party DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550981/need-a-way-to-reference-2-different-versions-of-the-same-3rd-party-dll)

Answer (score 1):

I found that in my case the 2 assemblies in my solution that I was using the alias to differentiate had the same actual dll name, hence only 1 of the 2 assemblies was there.

Renamed to be

```
Interfaces.Beta1.dll
```

and

```
Interfaces.v1.dll
```

Then it all worked again!
(not both of them being called Interfaces.dll)

Once I worked that out it seemed pretty obvious :)

Answer (score -3):

Set the target framework to .NET 4.5.1.